# What are my options for a hosted vps service with shell access?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, vps, linux, linode

Disclaimer (some folks marked this question as a duplicate):
I DO NOT want suggestions for things like a hosted wordpress providers, nor am I asking what web hosting is.  This question is not a duplicate of: [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements) -- I just want suggestions from other technologists about viable alternatives.

I've heard about [linode](http://www.linode.com/faq.cfm) which sounds promising.  I'd like recommendations for specific web hosts that provide VPS hosting providing a lot of control over the machine (like linode).  I want to install packages such as: tmux, python 2.7, a java runtime, node.js runtime, mysql, memcached, in-memory queuing libraries, etc.

In short, I want an "always on" machine for doing personal development projects, which may lead to commercial purposes in the future.  Some specifics and tools I'm looking for are:

- cheap! (personal use for now $0 - $30/mo)
- shell access (sudo access for package management on my own host VMs)
- control over dns
- ability to alter cpu/memory/disk resources as needed (depends on the project)
- Centos 6.x (or other linux OS that plays nice with AWS)

Some web searching led me down a rabbit hole (and annoying sales/marketing pitch).  A small list of hosting providers meeting the above criteria and some comparison of them from technologists would clarify the info I need to make an informed decision.